# Evaluate the line integral with the given closed curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

[image: Evaluate the line integral of the closed curve C oriented counterclockwise]

Evaluate the line integral of the closed curve C oriented counterclockwise

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Have you tried using the hint which gives the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I used Green's Theorem

Comment: You should add your attempts for to solve this problem,

Comment: You mean split the graph into rectangles and then evaluate the sum of the integrals, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Applying Green's Theorem

$ \int_C (Pdx + Qdy) = \iint_D (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}) dA$

When you find $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$, you will realize you get a number and your integral is that number multiplied by $\iint_D dA$. So simply calculate the area of the given closed path splitting into rectangles and squares, without integral. That should lead you to the answer.

Comment: ahh thank you, one more question, do I need to multiply each area by the constant from green's theorem or add up all the areas and then multiply?

Comment: Find the whole area for the closed path. Multiply by the number. That is your answer.